# Extract RSA private key from Cryptico.js

Tags: javascript, rsa, cryptico

I believe this is a pretty basic question, but I'm starting the studies in JavaScript and in RSA, so I'm a little bit lost. I just downloaded the library Cryptico, which gives me an easy to use RSA key gen/encryption/decryption. The public part of the generated RSA Key, can be extracted easily just using the command:

> publicKeyString(RsaKey)

Which is:

```
my.publicKeyString = function(rsakey) 
{
    pubkey = my.b16to64(rsakey.n.toString(16));
    return pubkey; 
}
```

The rsakey.n is defined while generating the key in the function:

```
function RSAGenerate(B, E)
{
    var rng = new SeededRandom();
    var qs = B >> 1;
    this.e = parseInt(E, 16);
    var ee = new BigInteger(E, 16);
    for (;;)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            this.p = new BigInteger(B - qs, 1, rng);
            if (this.p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).gcd(ee).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0 && this.p.isProbablePrime(10)) break;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            this.q = new BigInteger(qs, 1, rng);
            if (this.q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).gcd(ee).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0 && this.q.isProbablePrime(10)) break;
        }
        if (this.p.compareTo(this.q) <= 0)
        {
            var t = this.p;
            this.p = this.q;
            this.q = t;
        }
        var p1 = this.p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        var q1 = this.q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        var phi = p1.multiply(q1);
        if (phi.gcd(ee).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0)
        {
            this.n = this.p.multiply(this.q);
            this.d = ee.modInverse(phi);
            this.dmp1 = this.d.mod(p1);
            this.dmq1 = this.d.mod(q1);
            this.coeff = this.q.modInverse(this.p);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But the private part of the key, I just can't understand how to extract, so I'll be able to save public/private key parts and available for later using.

Library Documentation:
https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RSA is defined in such a way that the values contained in a public key make up a subset of the values contained in the private key. So your private key is already `rsakey`. Other public key schemes work differently where public and private key values are completely distinct.

Furthermore `rsakey.n` doesn't fully define the public key. You need at least the public exponent `e`. It is often simply set to 65537, so this might be hardcoded if you never need to change the key or upgrade the scheme. It's the `E` in `RSAGenerate`. It is ignored in this case, [because](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico#key-generation)

> A (seeded) random RSA key is generated with Tom Wu's RSA key generator with 3 as a hard-coded public exponent.

You can choose a similar encoding of the private key as the public key, but since it has to hold multiple values, I opted for JSON serialization:

```
(function(c){
    var parametersBigint = ["n", "d", "p", "q", "dmp1", "dmq1", "coeff"];

    c.privateKeyString = function(rsakey) {
        var keyObj = {};
        parametersBigint.forEach(function(parameter){
            keyObj[parameter] = c.b16to64(rsakey[parameter].toString(16));
        });
        // e is 3 implicitly
        return JSON.stringify(keyObj);
    }
    c.privateKeyFromString = function(string) {
        var keyObj = JSON.parse(string);
        var rsa = new RSAKey();
        parametersBigint.forEach(function(parameter){
            rsa[parameter] = parseBigInt(c.b64to16(keyObj[parameter].split("|")[0]), 16);
        });
        rsa.e = parseInt("03", 16);
        return rsa
    }
})(cryptico)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, do you a way to view or save the entire object 'rsakey'? Because when I save I see only [object Object]... And as I said, to use the same key later for encrypt/decrypt I need it saved somehow.

Comment: I added the private key serialiazation

Comment: Thank you. But I still unsuccessful in this job. Right now I feel a little shame, because you did something big and I still don't know how to do this work. All I need is to save the key for posterior use, because the way it was made, I dont have the key (at least the private) in some way to save and encrypt/decrypt things later... You got me?

Comment: No, I didn't got you. So you did you generate the RSA (private) key with `cryptico.generateRSAKey(passphrase, bitlength)`? If this is a system question, then you didn't provide any detail as to whether this is executed in the browser or on the server.

Comment: Yes I generate the key. And this is executed in the client side. But I want to have a link, for a download, poiting a variable with the key (private). This is part of a project that I'm still trying to develop, that's why I want to be able to save the private key, offering it via download.

Comment: So, your actual question is, how to download a private key file from the browser? If yes, then you should ask a new question now, but look for a duplicate beforehand and see what the file API can do. Editing your question to include your new scope is not good, because I couldn't answer it and this would somewhat diminish the value my answer. Now, do you still have a problem generating a string representation of the private key or is there something else?